# Cycles cannot contain other cycles in graph theory?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, definition

In my computer science background, I have thought that cycles can contain other cycles in a graph, as they have been defined for me in cs classes merely as a path which starts an ends at the same vertex. However, I am presented with this algebraic definition of a cycle:

> A cycle (or circuit) is a sequence of edges $\left\{v_1, v_2\right\},\left\{v_2, v_3\right\}, \ldots,\left\{v_{n-2}, v_{n-1}\right\},\left\{v_{n-1}, v_n\right\},\left\{v_n, v_1\right\}$, where $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are distinct.

Due to the variables representing these vertices being distinct, there can be no cycle within a cycle. I am wondering whether this definition precluding a cycle from being within a cycle is the standard one in discrete mathematics and graph theory, as it clashes with my cs background.

Comment: You can distinguish between *cycle* and *simple cycle* (the definition you quoted). Take also into account that just like you find variability in common languages, there is also variability in definitions in mathematics. People can choose or not to include the requirement of different vertices or to distinguish or not between simple or not simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you should check definitions in the article or textbook. Different authors give different meaning to the same terms. According to Bondy, Murty and their Graph theory with applications, *cycle* is a closed trail with no repeated vertex other than origin and terminus, i. e. cycle is a closed path.
[image]
[image]
[image]

On the other hand some authors say *path* instead of *trail* and *simple path* instead of *path*. Then the same happens with cycles: they use *cycle* for any *closed trail* and *simple cycle* for *cycle*.

Also it is possible to define cycle as a subgraph rather than as a sequence. But still the same difference occurs: some authors say that $2$-regular connected subgraph is a *cycle*, and some others say that it is a *simple cycle*.

Answer (score 0):

Standard definitions of a cycle are usually equivalent to the "algebraic" one you provided. This way, we can talk about *"the 6-cycle"* without this term being ambiguous between a hexagon and two triangles adjoined at a vertex. Otherwise, we would have to say *a 6-cycle*.